# how to fix the missing type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
 DATA = {
    data: [
      { id: "1r5WioSdYLVqp", row: 1, assetType: "1r5WioSdYLVqp", status: "" },
      { id: "w1muKlmY4lsR", row: 2, assetType: "w1muKlmY4lsR", status: "" },
      { id: "1foDN2HDHiAbT", row: 3, assetType: "1foDN2HDHiAbT", status: "" }
    ]
  };

  new = { row: 1, assetType: "1fKBO4w0XHg7H", status: "ACTIVE" }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.DATA);

    this.DATA['data'].forEach((dt, index) => {
      if (dt.row === this.new.row) {
        this.DATA['data'][index] = this.new;
      }
    });

    console.log(this.DATA)
  }
```

What I'm trying to do here is to update the data based on the row number. but on the new it has no ID. but I'm getting an error which is:
[image]

Comment: shouldn't you be generating an id at the time that you create the item?

Comment: If you can't do what @Rick suggested (always have an ID), you can update your Type to allow the null value: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#nullable-types

Comment: @Estradiaz that has nothing to do with the error

Comment: He wants to _replace_ the row with a new one. Using something like `Object.assign()` would mean something very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can indicate that an item my not have an `id` by using a type annotation indicating that it is optional.

First, let's declare a type:

```
interface Item {
  id?: string;
  row: number;
  assetType: string;
  status: string;
}
```

The `?` on `id` above indicates that it is an optional property. It may or may not be specified.

Now let's apply it:

```
DATA: { data: Item[] } = {
  data: [
    { id: "1r5WioSdYLVqp", row: 1, assetType: "1r5WioSdYLVqp", status: "" },
    { id: "w1muKlmY4lsR", row: 2, assetType: "w1muKlmY4lsR", status: "" },
    { id: "1foDN2HDHiAbT", row: 3, assetType: "1foDN2HDHiAbT", status: "" }
  ]
};

new = { row: 1, assetType: "1fKBO4w0XHg7H", status: "ACTIVE" }
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.DATA);

  this.DATA.data.forEach((dt, index) => {
    if (dt.row === this.new.row) {
      this.DATA.data[index] = this.new; // no error.
    }
  });

  console.log(this.DATA)
}
```

Notice, that I've snuck in an additional type, in the form of the object literal type `{ data: Item[] }`. This was done because of the nesting of the code in the question. If `DATA` has only one property, `data`, I would unwrap it to simplify things.

Then you could write

```
data: Item[] = [
  { id: "1r5WioSdYLVqp", row: 1, assetType: "1r5WioSdYLVqp", status: "" },
  { id: "w1muKlmY4lsR", row: 2, assetType: "w1muKlmY4lsR", status: "" },
  { id: "1foDN2HDHiAbT", row: 3, assetType: "1foDN2HDHiAbT", status: "" }
]
```

Which is easier to read and to write. Alternately, we can declare a type for the outer object

```
interface DataWrapper {
  data: Item[];
}

DATA: DataWrapper = {
  data: [
    { id: "1r5WioSdYLVqp", row: 1, assetType: "1r5WioSdYLVqp", status: "" },
    { id: "w1muKlmY4lsR", row: 2, assetType: "w1muKlmY4lsR", status: "" },
    { id: "1foDN2HDHiAbT", row: 3, assetType: "1foDN2HDHiAbT", status: "" }
  ]
}
```

Lastly, and unrelatedly, we can clean this code up a bit by removing the unecessary `forEach`.

```
const index = this.DATA.data.findIndex(({row}) => row === this.new.row);
if (index !== -1) {
  this.DATA.data[index] = this.new;
}
```

Comment: i think this a most relevant solution ,  if you want to continue  without the "id" Object property  {id?: string;} => Question marks on Typescript variable are used to mark that variable as an optional variable

Answer (score 0):

set null on a property `id` of the variable `new`.

```
  new = { id: null, row: 1, assetType: "1fKBO4w0XHg7H", status: "ACTIVE" }
```

Comment: This doesn't work when using `strict`/`strictNullChecks`, which is the de facto and default configuration for TypeScript. Instead, `id` should be optional, accept `undefined`, or accept `null`. This requires using a type annotation or type assertion.

Answer (score 0):

this is probably a case where typescript is forcing you to write better code. I can't think of any reason why you would want to generate data with a null id. Why not something like this:

```
var id = generateId();
new = { id: id, row: 1, assetType: "1fKBO4w0XHg7H", status: "ACTIVE" };
```

Comment: Maybe id doesn't exist until he saves it to a backend of some kind.

Comment: @AluanHaddad possibly, but I don't know what possible value there could be to inserting that into your dataset without an id. it seems like better designed code would eliminate the problem.

Comment: Let's say I am saving an object with an array valued property to a database via an http backend that interfaces with a database that automatically generates ids. This is actually relatively common when working with relational/SQL databases and `SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyDb ON` is not something you want to do casually.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a type for your object in data and set the type accordingly like below so it will help you hint what you're missing to avoid this kind of confusion:

```
interface DataType {
 id: string
 row: number
 assetType: string
 status: string
}

DATA: Record<'data', DataType[]> = { data: [
  { id: "1r5WioSdYLVqp", row: 1, assetType: "1r5WioSdYLVqp", status: "" },
  { id: "w1muKlmY4lsR", row: 2, assetType: "w1muKlmY4lsR", status: "" },
  { id: "1foDN2HDHiAbT", row: 3, assetType: "1foDN2HDHiAbT", status: "" }
]} 

new: DataType = { 
  id: 'yourNewId', 
  row: 1, 
  assetType: "1fKBO4w0XHg7H", 
  status: "ACTIVE" 
}
```